# Customized bonus questions in exam class

Tags: exam

I'm using the `exam` class (with the `addpoints` option) to create assignments, and I want to create some bonus questions. I have a customized question format that looks like this:

```
\qformat{Question \thequestion: [\totalpoints]}
```

which works fine for regular questions.

However, the \totalpoints command doesn't return a value for bonus questions, and so those questions are incorrectly marked as having 0 points.

I hacked this by redefining \qformat (before the bonus questions) to be

```
\qformat{Question \thequestion: [\totalbonuspoints]}
```

which works fine. But I'd rather have a single designation that works for all question (bonus or not). How might I do that ?

note: I could have used \thepoints in the definition, but some of my questions have parts, and so \totalpoints is needed to add up the points.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the source of exam.cls there is a `if@bonus` that you can use to test if you are typesetting a bonus or a regular question. Hacking a bit you can do something like

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\thetotalpoints{%
  \if@bonus
    [\totalbonuspoints\ bonus points]
  \else
    [\totalpoints\ points]
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\qformat{Question \thequestion: \thetotalpoints \hfill}
```

Comment: oh that is neat. worked like a charm. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

The betatest version of exam.cls creates the command `\bonusqformat` that does for bonus questions what the command `\qformat` does for regular questions.  You can get a copy of version 2.318beta of exam.cls from [this web page](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/#ExamCls).
Using that version of exam.cls, you can say

```
\qformat{Question \thequestion: [\totalpoints]\hfill}
\bonusqformat{Question \thequestion: [\totalbonuspoints]\hfill}
```

or

```
\qformat{Question \thequestion:\dotfill [\totalpoints]}
\bonusqformat{Bonus Question \thequestion:\dotfill [\totalbonuspoints]}
```

or whatever other variant you like.